# How to implement drag and drop feature

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i want to make a application in this app user create flow   chart through drag and drop images 
like edraw software in computer please tell me how to implement this 
Thans in advance

Answer (score 2):

A sample:

```
private void dragImage() {
    imgLogo.setOnLongClickListener(new
            OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("dot",
                    // "Dot : " + v.toString());
                    ClipData data = ClipData
                            .newPlainText("dot",
                                    "Oops!\r\nWe are pleased that we have such clever customers! ;)");

                    MyDragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(
                            v);
                    v.startDrag(data, myShadow, (Object) v, 0);

                    return false;
                }
            });
    imgLogo.setClickable(true);
    imgLogo.setFocusable(true);
    imgLogo.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();

            // if (myShadow != null)
            // myShadow.setCurrentPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
            switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: {
                imgLogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
                // Hide the surprise again
                imgLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Report the drop/no-drop result to the user
                final boolean dropped = event.getResult();
                // tvGalleryLblQty.setText("ended");
            }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
                final boolean dropped = event.getResult();
            }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```